# Deterministic choices of endorsing peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am curious how does Fabric choose among one of selected Organizations in an "OR"-type Endorsement Policy. Is it a random choice or does it follow a predetermined logic?

For instance, let's say that I have a following policy :

*OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member')*

Now, let's say that the Endorsing Peer which is supposed to process an incoming transaction proposal belongs to Org1.

Because of uncertainty about network connectivity and availability of other organizations, Org1 would be a preferred entity elected for endorsement (because it happens locally on that very same peer).

However, is this the case in Hyperledger Fabric?

Any help understanding the above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric clients should be aware of the endorsement policies and it's up to them to decide on endorsing peers. So in your example with:

```
OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member')
```

client should know that in order to get valid transaction it has to be endorsed by either someone from org1 or org2 or org3. So client could send transaction proposal to some peer into org1 and wait until get response. An alternative strategy would be to send transaction proposal to 3 peers one from each organization.

Once client collects enough endorsement it will submit transaction to the ordering service and prior to commit peer will ensure that endorsement policy being satisfied. Now please note that endorsement policy doesn't specifies exact endorsement peers, but just saying that it has to be someone from that org with certificate approved by org root CA.

So right now client has to know endorsement policies and being aware of the membership to being able sent transaction proposals, however there work in progress [FAB-5451](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5451), to provide service discovery based capabilities so client will be able to dynamically learn policies and will be able to query for set of endorsing peers.

Comment: Thanks! I was curious what behaviour can I expect from endorsement policy when a peer receiving a transaction candidate from the client has an endorsing peer status and belongs to one of the Orgs embedded in an endorsement policy. Would there be a preference for this Org instead of other Orgs which are remote to that transaction candidate?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not following you, can you try to rephrase?

Comment: Apologies for lack of clarity - let's assume an application is configured to connect to a specific peer that is owned by a business network member. This peer is an endorser and belongs to Org1. Endorsement policy says that to validate a transaction candidate, Org1, or Org2 or Org3 should endorse it. The question is: Will endorsement policy always randomly choose between one of these organizations or will it choose endorsement from the first responding endorser? If the latter is the case, it is very likely that Org1 peer will always have an advantage over other Orgs. Thanks for a comment.

Comment: Endorsement policy doesn't choose anything, it's only denotes a rule of which organizations should be approving(endorsing) transactions. During the validation phase all endorsing peers from all organization are equal in that sense, e.g. it doesn't really matter who will be endorsing transaction as long as rule is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be better to step back from talking directly to peers and orderers?  use channel instead.    always speaking only to specific elements is SO fragile.